# issue in disabling submit button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am iterating a list , and displaying its values in  textboxes. 
there is  two textboxes with name `checkquantity` & `quantity` whose values i am iterating from a list.

Now users have to enter the quantity values, if they enter the quantity values more then the allocated quantity. Then i  have to disable the submit button.

*This is my problem:*
From my below code , submit button is diasabling for first time only. i.e. if i enter invalid values  for first time then my code is working fine but if again i enter valid values in another text-box  then my button is enabling. But it should not enable since in first textbox invalid values are entered.

**Note:** Users can only enter values in textbox name `quantity` and this textbox will be validated from the textbox `checkquantity`.

Please check my below code and suggest me a solution for this.

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var q = +$tr.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
    var cq = +$tr.find('input[name^="checkquantity"]').val();

    if (q > cq) {
        $('#submtbtnId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('#submtbtnId').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
----------------------------------- in
while loop my list is iterating 
{ 
  <tr> 
    <td width = "10%"> 
      <input type = "text" name = "quantity"values = "" id = "quantity" / >   
      <input type = "text" name = "checkquantity" disable = "disable"
          values = "random values coming from my list   
                 eg. 5 or 9 ..." / > < /td>   
  </tr >
}

------------------------- 
 < input type = "submit" id = "submtbtnId" / >​
```

Comment: I think because you only have the function defined for `input[name="quantity"]`. What happens if you make a similar function for `input[name="checkquantity"]`?

Comment: It should be disabled, with a "d". It's an adjective, not a verb.

Comment: @Diodeus Thanks. But can you suggest any answer for my question. Rather then checking my spellings.

Comment: He did. `disable = "disable"` should be `disabled = "disabled"`, and that should fix it.

Comment: @crowjonah No, still same. I assume you have understood my above  problem.

Comment: "spelling" counts when it's CODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the case every time in the keyup event check all the textboxes by iterating over them..

**UPDATE**

Looks like the issue is with the attribute named **values** .
If you are trying to access the value using `.val()` then it is supposed to be **value**.

Added the `return false;` condition to make sure it breaks out of the loop when the condition fails.

**Secondly** there was one more issue.. Lets say the input **is empty** .. So when you convert that to a number then it is **0** and the **comparison always fails..**

So i have added a check condition if the field is not empty , only then convert to the number

```
$('input[name="quantity"]').on('keyup', function() {
    var check = false;
    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $tr = $(this);
        var q = $tr.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
        if(q != ''){
            q = +q;
        }
        var cq = +$tr.find('input[name^="checkquantity"]').val();
        if (q !== '' && q > cq) {
            check = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (check) {
        $('#submtbtnId').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#submtbtnId').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/egZxQ/4/)**

Comment: Same problem. I am struggling so much for this. please help

Comment: can you crate a fiddle for that case.. It is difficult to say where exactly your problem is ..

Comment: Looks like the problem is the attribute values.. It is supposed to be value instead to access them using .val()

Comment: **Update:** just now i paste all my Jsp code in my above question as update (Please check it above)  .  I am developing a project in Struts2(javas framwork).

Comment: logic is wrong. "Entered quantity value should not be greater then the  value in `checkquantity` textbox

Comment: @AshutoshSingh .. The logic is not wrong .. I just flipped them so that I can escape using both the if and else... Writing this way requirs to use only if condition

Comment: you have made solution just opposite of my question. Can you update it again. i want like this **diasable the `submit` button if value entered inside the `quantity` textbox is greater then the available values inside the textbox ``**

Comment: @AshutoshSingh .. just replace the < with > and it should work fine.. Also updated the post

Comment: Yeah i did it before only. Its simple logic, I should not ask about that.